# How do i get value of inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td class="stockQuantity">
  <input class="form-control" id="Cart1" name="qty_req" required="required" type="text" value=""><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="appendCart(event,4,4,'Bottles',444,4)" class="btn btn-primary">
    Add To Cart
   </button>
</td>
```

**Js function**

```
 function appendCart(e, id, inwardRegId, stockName, quantity, inwardItemFId) {
      
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;



        console.log(e);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(inwardRegId);
        console.log(stockName);
        console.log(quantity);
        console.log(inwardItemFId);

       // undefined 
        var inputVal = $(this).find('input[type="text"].stockQuantity').val();

        alert(inputVal);
}
```

How do I get the value in the input box above it using jQuery, keep getting undefined value when executed.

**Note**

- The inputbox is in a for loop of input boxes with the same id "Cart1" for some reason I can't give it a unique id.
- Also I've got a lead so by setting a breakpoint on the `var target = e.target || e.srcElement;` and looking at the local variables the value of the input box related to that button is in taget>offsetParent>childNodes>value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved
Using `target.offsetParent.childNodes[0].value` thank you everyone for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the input box of yours has no class called `stockQuantity`. It is the `td` element that has it.

What you can do is this:

```js
 function appendCart(e, id, inwardRegId, stockName, quantity, inwardItemFId) {
      
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;



        console.log(e);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(inwardRegId);
        console.log(stockName);
        console.log(quantity);
        console.log(inwardItemFId);

       // undefined 
        var inputVal = $("input#Cart1").val();

        alert(inputVal);
}
```

```html
<td class="stockQuantity">
  <input class="form-control" id="Cart1" name="qty_req" required="required" type="text" value=""><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="appendCart(event,4,4,'Bottles',444,4)" class="btn btn-primary">
    Add To Cart
   </button>
</td>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tell me if this worked on you!

Comment: this does work but let us say that it is in a for loop of input boxes with the same id "Cart1" for some reason I can't give it a unique id. Is there another way you could still get the value of the input box?

Comment: Then you can just do this `var inputVal = $("td.stockQuantity > input").val();`

Comment: sorry this would do the same thing as your previous answer as all the td's would have a class of stockQuantity

Comment: Hmmm... try this `var inputVal = $('input[type="text"]').val();` or `var inputVal = $('input[type="text"].stockQuantity').val();`

Comment: don't work but I've got a lead 
so by setting a breakpoint on the 
`var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`
and looking at the local variables 
the value of the input box related to that button is in taget>offsetParent>childNodes>value

Answer (score 1):

**Problems**

**1.** The  `$(this)` placement is wrong, basically what you are saying is find the input in the button, which it cannot find , the context is wrong that's why you cant  find the value of the input field

**2.** There is no input with a classname `.stockQuantity`

**Solutions**

1. `$("input#Cart1").val();`
2. `$("body").find('input[type="text"]').val()`

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

if this is going to be the only input in the page then you can use the following snippet:

```
var inputVal = $('input[type="text"]')[0].value;
console.log('IV: ',inputVal)
```

or simply

```
$("input#Cart1").val();
```

## Solution 2

### for multiple input case

Now considering your code snippet, i see you are looking to find the input field using jquery methods.

for this to work, you must bind a click event after render

```
  $(document).on("click", "#button1", function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).siblings('input[id="Cart1"]')[0].value
    alert(inputVal);
  })
```

similarly your HTML will be like this

```
<button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Add To Cart
</button>
```

Let me know if you need any more help, thanks